# Numerical Integration of triple integral

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to perform the following integration:

$$f(x)=\int_{0.01}^{x-0.01} \int_{0.1}^{10} \int_{0.1}^{10} \frac{8(x-x_1)^2Ep^2}{2x_1^2 Ep^2 s_2^2+2(x-x_1)^2 Ep^2 s_1s_2-s_1s_2^2-4x_1(x-x_1)Ep^2 \sqrt{s_1}\sqrt{s_2}s_2}ds_2ds_1dx_1,$$

and then plot $f(x)$ for $x \in[0,1]$. In the above expression, $Ep$ is given. Such computation cannot be performed analytically, thus one has to take the numerical approach.

I wrote the following lines of codes in Mathematica but apparently do not work.

```
Ep=10;
f[x_, x1_, s1_, s2_] := 
  (8*(x - x1)^2*Ep^2)/
   (2*(x1^2*Ep^2*s2^2) + 2*((x - x1)^2*Ep^2*s1*s2) - (s1*s2^2) - 
     4*x1*(x - x1)*(Ep^2*Sqrt[s1]*Sqrt[s2]*s2))

Ng[x_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[f[x, x1, s1, s2], {x1, 0.01, x-0.01}, {s1, 0.1, 10}, {s2, 0.1, 10}]

Plot[Ng[x], {x,0.001, 1}]
```

Does anyone know a clever way to do this integration?

Comment: Add to your code `Ep ="put some number" ;`

Comment: I have already given a value to Ep in my codes. I forgot to mention it in my previous post (already fixed).

Comment: High-dimensional integrals are very hard and time-consuming to compute. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `ListLinePlot` instead of `Plot` and to use a smaller precision goal. Below is an example.

```
Ep = 10;
f[x_?NumericQ, x1_?NumericQ, s1_?NumericQ, 
   s2_?NumericQ] := (8*(x - x1)^2*Ep^2)/(2*(x1^2*Ep^2*s2^2) + 
     2*((x - x1)^2*Ep^2*s1*s2) - (s1*s2^2) - 
     4*x1*(x - x1)*(Ep^2*Sqrt[s1]*Sqrt[s2]*s2));

Ng[x_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   f[x, x1, s1, s2], {x1, 0.01, x - 0.01}, {s1, 0.1, 10}, {s2, 0.1, 
    10}, PrecisionGoal -> 3, 
   Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
```

The following command produces lots of messages -- do look into them in order to determine do you believe the obtained integral estimates.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 res = Table[{x, Ng[x]}, {x, 0.001, 1, 0.025}];
]

(* {42.716, Null} *)


ListLinePlot[res, PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Comment: Plot very similar to :`ListLinePlot@
 Table[{x, x^2*RandomReal[{-30*x, 30*x}]}, {x, 0.001, 1, 0.025}]` :)

Comment: Thank you very much :-) This is indeed what I was expecting for.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Right -- with my code you are able to do that comparison. (Speeding up the computations is what OP wanted.) Also, as I mentioned in my answer, the error messages have to be studied in order to determine are the integral estimates adequate.

Comment: @Radonirina Great, I am glad you find the answer useful.